# How to redraw the list with updated information using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the html code `

```
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="home">
     <div data-role="header">
        <h1>site Details</h1>
     </div>
     <div data-role="content">
         <a href="#Site entry1" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Enter the details of site</a>
         <a href="#Modify site" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Modify site details</a>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="Site entry1">
     <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#home" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
        <h1>Welcome To enter the details of site</h1>
     </div>
     <div id="generalList"></div>
     <div data-role="content">
        <div class="content-primary">
        <form>
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="sitename">Site name:</label>
                <input type="text" sitename="name" id="siteName" value=""  />
            </li>
            <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="siteno">Site name:</label>
                <input type="text" siteno="siteno" id="siteNo" value=""  />
            </li>

            <a href="#Site entry2" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Next</a>
        </ul>
        </form>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="Site entry2">

    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="content-primary">
        <form>
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="moduleNo">moduleNo:</label>
                <input type="text" moduleNo="moduleNo" id="moduleNo" value=""  />
            </li>
            <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button></div>
                    </fieldset>
            </li>

        </ul>

        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    <a href="#Site entry1"  data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">previous</a>
    <a href="#Site entry3" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Next</a>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="page" id="Site entry3">

    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="content-primary">
        <form>
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="executiveNo">executiveNo:</label>
                <input type="text" executiveNo="executiveNo" id="executiveNo" value=""  />
            </li>

            <li class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><button id="btn_3" type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button></div>
                    </fieldset>
            </li>

        </ul>

        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    <a href="#Site entry2" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">previous</a>
    <a href="#home"  data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
    </div>
 </div>

<div data-role="page" id="Modify site">
    <div data-role="header">
    <a href="home" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
    <h1>List of sites </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <button id="btm_4" type="submit" data-theme="a">modify</button>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

I have created the list of fields from different pages with the code below

```
function makesite(site){
    var li = '<ul data-role="listview" >';
            $('body').find('[data-role="fieldcontain"]').each(function(key, value){         
                var title = $(this).find('label').html();  
                var val = $(this).find('[type="text"]').val();     
                li += '<li>'+title+' '+val+'</li>';
            });
            li +='</ul>';           
            $('#content').html(li).trigger('create');
             $('ul').listview('refresh');}
```

But the problem is I need to display the List of site added with sitename on clicking modify button in page with id "modifysite". where site, site name,site no,executive no, module no are  global variables.

I have tried with the code below

```
Function redrawsites(site){
 var ul = makesite(site);

    $('#content').html(ul).trigger('create');
}
```

Comment: Syntax error on `/$('ul').listview('refresh');}`, leave out the `/` (is that actually in your code?)

Comment: i like how your ul is called li :P